# Upload DHT22 Sensor Data to Xively Feed

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, sensors, xively

I am trying to modify some of the predefined code that exists for the [`DHT22`](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/DHT22.pdf) sensor. I would like to modify [`Adafruit's DHT_Driver`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/blob/master/Adafruit_DHT_Driver/Adafruit_DHT.c) so that it returns an array corresponding to the `Temperature` value and `Humidity` value that the sensor outputs. I would like to make this change so that I can utilize the output array in a Python snippet. Namely, I want to use the output array values to upload data to a `Xively` feed.

I am looking for something similar to this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import os
import eeml

# Xively variables specific to my account.
API_KEY = 'API Key Here'
FEED = 'FEED # Here'
API_URL = '/v2/feeds/{feednum}.xml' .format(feednum = FEED)

# Continuously read data from the DHT22 sensor and upload
# the results to the Xively feed. 
while True:
    # Read the data from the sensor.
    sensorData = .... // Call on the main method within the DHT_Driver.c file
    temp_C = sensorData[0]
    humidity = sensorData[1]

    if DEBUG:
        print("sensorData:\t", sensorData)
        print("\n")

    if LOGGER:
        # Initialize the users Xively account.
        pac = eeml.Pachube(API_URL, API_KEY)

        # Prepare the data to be uploaded to the Xively
        # account.
        # temp_C & humidity are extracted from their indices
        # above.
        pac.update([eeml.Data(0, temp_C, unit=eeml.Celsius())])
        pac.update([eeml.Data(1, humidity, unit=eeml.%())])

        # Upload the data to the Xively account.
        pac.put()

        # Wait 30 seconds to avoid flooding the Xively feed.
        time.sleep(30)
```

I need some feedback on getting the Temperature and Humidity vaules from the sensor. It must utilize `C` because Python isn't fast enough to process the data from the sensor. Ideally I could just return an array containing the two values and access the values like this:

```
temp_C = sensorData[0]
humidity = sensorData[1]
```

Also, if, within this Python snippet, I were to call on the main method within the DHT_Driver.c file would this be limited by the Python interpreter (i.e. will the C based program run with similar performance to a Python based program)?

I am very unfamiliar with Python and I am just beginning C so if there are any suggestions and or positive criticism, please feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should update the code to use [official Python module](http://xively.github.io/xively-python/) provided by Xively.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import os
import xively

# Xively variables specific to my account.
API_KEY = ....
FEED_ID = ....


# Continuously read data from the DHT22 sensor and upload
# the results to the Xively feed. 
while True:

    # Initialize Xively library and fetch the feed
    feed = xively.XivelyAPIClient(API_KEY).feeds.get(FEED_ID)

    feed.datastreams = [
        xively.Datastream(id='tempertature', current_value=getTemperature()),
        xively.Datastream(id='humidity', current_value=getHumidity()),
    ]
    # Upload the data into the Xively feed
    feed.update()

    # Wait 30 seconds to avoid flooding the Xively feed.
    time.sleep(30)
```

Regarding the sensor driver, I would take a look at [AirPi](https://github.com/xively/AirPi/tree/master/interfaces).

Comment: The issue isn't so much in uploading the data to the Xively feed, it is more in the `getTemperature()` and `getHumidity()` functions. What I need, primarily, is a suggestion as to how I should do this.

I have a C based driver that runs the sensor (see links above), but I need a way to easily get that data back and use in within the Python script.

Comment: @Jonathan, did you take a look at the AirPi code under the link I posted above?

Comment: I have taken a look at the AirPi code, but I can't seem to get it to work. I continue to get errors upon running the code. See my post over at the Raspberry Pi Forums [http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=56853&p=429183#p429183]